# XCODE: How will the size of iPhone 12 affect constraints and storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I haven't updated Xcode since the iPhone 12 was released.

I am wondering if there is a new update in which the iPhone 12 is now the main storyboard interface phone, and it's different in size from the iPhone 11?

I want to release a small app that I just finished development on, but do I need to update and adjust for new constraints for a different size phone (i.e. iPhone 12)?  If so, what happens to my already created storyboard on the iPhone 11 model? Does it stay or do I have to remodel or what? Any help on how this will work with Xcode and constraints and whatnot is much appreciated.

Comment: Two things. A quick check at developer.apple.com shows that Xcode 12.1 GM seed was put out there on the day of the iPhone announcements - if that is unavailable for you, I'd expect it on the App Store sometime next week (Tuesday afternoon Cupertino time?). Second, assuming you are using constraints properly, you should be fine - that's what auto layout is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't have to change much as the sizes are quite similar. The storyboard should automatically resize based on what iPhone you are building for.

The iPhone 12 Pro Max is only just a bit bigger than the iPhone 11 Pro Max, meaning there shouldn't be much to change there. Also, The iPhone 12 Pro's size is just in between the iPhone X and iPhone 11.

You can see the below diagram for more information:

[image: iphone size diagram]

Comment: as far as I know, the iPhone XR, iPhone 11, iPhone 12, and iPhone 12 Pro all have the same screen size, however, the pixel density is different with the iPhone XR/11 series and the iPhone 12 series. The screen-to-body ratio size is what has changed.